# How to exclude some classes from legend?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend, classification, arcgis-10.5

I have a raster file with 8 classifications (all numerical), however the last classification I have coloured with 'no colour' so it does not show up on the map, however I also wish to exclude this class from the legend. Is there a way to remove certain classes from the legend?

I am using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.5

Answer (score 1):

After creating the legend you can convert it to a graphic item.  Then ungroup the graphic and delete out the unwanted class.